# Command text was not set

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

Good day I am having an error which states that command text was not set when I try to add data.

```
 Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click    
        Try
            connString = (dbsource)
            myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
            myConnection.Open()
            Dim str As String    
            str = "Add [Bill] set [Log_ID] =  ' " & TextBox2.Text & " ' where [Bill_ID] = " & TextBox1.Text & " " 
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        Catch err As Exception
            MsgBox(err.Message)    
        End Try
        Try
            Dim str As String
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try 
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your first command is created but never executed. Your second command is using an empty string, `str` is created and then used as command-text immediately on the next line without ever having its value set to any sql, hence the "command text not set" error.

Comment: There is a good deal wrong there.  Never concat values into a string for SQL, use DB Parameters; `Add` is not valid SQL; when the IDE indents like that it creates a new `block level scope` so those 2 blocks are using new vars; dispose of your command.  I an not sure what yoiu are up to with `Add [Bill]...`

Answer (score 0):

You have two Try/Catch blocks in that code. Each Try/Catch block has variables named `str` and `cmd`. However, those are two **different** `str` variables and two **different** `cmd` variables. The Try/Catch blocks each define their own scope, and just re-declaring a new variable with the same name in a new scope doesn't give that variable the same value as you had in a previous scope.

There are some other things in here that suggest you may have experience with vb6/vbscript era code, or an instructor who had experience with that older code. VB.Net is a whole new animal, with new language idioms. You want something more like this:

```vb
'Separate your Database code from your user interface code
Public Sub SetBillLogItem(LogID As String, BillID As String)
    'Don't bother with Try/Catch in this method.
    'Let exceptions bubble up to be handled in the presentation layer

    ' What database are you using? "Add" isn't valid SQL
    ' Also, notice how this string is a constant.
    Dim sql As String = "Add [Bill] set [Log_ID] = ? where [Bill_ID] = ? "

    'Using block guarantees the connection is closed properly even if an exception is thrown
    ' Also, .Net **strongly** prefers you to create a new connection object for most DB operations
    Using cn  As New OleDbConnection(dbsource), _
          cmd As New OleDBCommand(sql, cn)

        'ALWAYS use parameters to set values for your SQL. 
        'Guessing a parameter type and length here, you might want Integer instead
        cmd.Parameters.Add("LogId", OleDbType.VarWChar, 10).Value = LogId
        cmd.Parameters.Add("BillID", OleDbType.VarWChar, 10).Value = BillID

        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'No need to call cn.Close(), Using block takes care of this for us in a safer way
    End Using
End Sub

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click    
    Try
        SetBillLogItem(TextBox2.Text, TextBox1.Text)
    Catch err As Exception
        MsgBox(err.Message)    
    End Try 
End Sub
```

And once more without all my extra comments, so you can see this isn't any more code than you already had:

```vb
Public Sub SetBillLogItem(LogID As String, BillID As String)
    Dim sql As String = "Add [Bill] set [Log_ID] = ? where [Bill_ID] = ? "
    Using cn  As New OleDbConnection(dbsource), _
          cmd As New OleDBCommand(sql, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("LogId", OleDbType.VarWChar, 10).Value = LogId
        cmd.Parameters.Add("BillID", OleDbType.VarWChar, 10).Value = BillID

        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click    
    Try
        SetBillLogItem(TextBox2.Text, TextBox1.Text)
    Catch err As Exception
        MsgBox(err.Message)    
    End Try 
End Sub
```

Comment: `Add` is not a valid SQL command, should suggest to use `Update` as the query indicates, he wants to update.

Comment: Yep, that is indicated in the comments above that line of code, but I stopped at just a comment because I haven't ruled out the idea the OLE provider might be connecting to some less-common kind of DB which uses an ADD statement for doing upserts.

Comment: I saw that too, you just indicated that `"Add" isn't valid SQL`. but you didn't suggest to use `Update`. Otherwise your answer will produce another error.

Comment: Why the sql syntax wasn't altered is clearly explained, and the quality of this answer is nowhere near what is described as being deserving of a downvote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)